# How I to run custom "docker" command in Azure Web Application?

Tags: azure, docker

I'm setting up container in azure. But container turning off itself because of no `-it` arg in run command.
[Azure Conteiner Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYFbg.png)

My plan's change run command like

```
docker run -it -d -p 3000:3000 ikbalkazanc/dashboard:dev
```

In Container settings, have the "startup file" setting but appends the input to the end of the command. So azure don't provide this change. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can't change the docker command as you want. The container turns off possibly because there is no running application inside to make the container continue to run. Of course, you can use the startup file to add the command to run the application in the container. Note that this startup file will override the `CMD` command in the Dockerfile of the docker image.

Comment: i know program running in container because when i run in my pc with "-it" command, it running smootly. Also attached CMD command as `npm start` in dockerfile. But you said it're overwrite. It was useful I learned that. Thanks

Comment: @mrpetrisah What about the situation now? Does you solve the issue?

Comment: i couldn't solve the problem. i assigned the problem to my mentor. if he can solve, i'll share here

Comment: @mrpetrisah You may try to set the environment variable `WEBSITE_PORT` with the value of the port you exposed in the Dockerfile. And as I said that you can't change the docker command that the Azure Web App use.

Comment: I think your solition'll not work but even so i'll try.

Comment: @mrpetrisah Any updates on this question? Does it solve your problem? Please let me know if you have any responses.